# Generar fichero WebServices.xml en Java8

Tags: webservice, java-8, wsdl

Me he creado un proyecto WSDL para una aplicación en Java 8 basándome en otro que ya existía antes.

En el proyecto existente veo que existe un fichero llamado WebServices.xml y me gustaría saber si es necesario. En caso afirmativo, me gustaría saber cómo se genera o conque me copie el existente al mío y realizar modificación de adaptación ya me valdría.

Utiliza la herramienta Eclipse.

Muchas gracias